# How does an SNMP agent map the correct data to the corresponding Object identifier

Tags: networking, snmp, mib

For example, sending a GET request to receive how many hours a device has been on for. You send the OID value with the GET request from the manager to an agent, so the agent knows which MIB to traverse into etc... But once it has checked and validated the OID exists how does the correct data get mapped to that specific OID in order to send it back?

Thanks.

Comment: Because once you know the OID you know what data is required. Uncelar what the issue is here.

Comment: How does the data get paired with the correct OID

Comment: As the answer below indicates, this question cannot be answered. For an agent like #SNMP Agent, it relies on each `ISnmpObject` derived objects to query the data from the underlying operating system, https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/en/latest/samples/agent-development.html#objectstore-and-isnmpobject

Comment: I have been reading about this all day - My first new understanding is that the agent isn't the device itself, but SNMP software that collects information about the device. Is this collection process done automatically? Where is the data stored when the agent gathers it? p.s thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It is very specific to SNMP agent implementation. SNMP does not cover this part. It is up to you as SNMP agent developer to decide how you bind OIDs and values.

Usually, it is some sort of hash table that maps oid to value.

Comment: Hash table might not be the correct data structure (as OIDs forms a tree in fact). But I agree it is agent implementation dependent.